# I am trying to find total Number of Digits using counter variable in javascript but output is always 324+ than the required

Tags: javascript

```js
var num = 233826;
var count = 0;
do {
  num = num/10;
  ++count;
} while (num > 0)
document.write("Total words are ", count);
```

output is >>>>>Total words are 330

if I write >>>>> document.write("Total words are ", count-324) then it gives me the required output which is (6)

Comment: So, `num` is going to be `233826`,`23382.6`,`2338.26`,`233.826`,`. . .`,`0.00000233826`. See where we're hitting a problem?

Comment: Cant you just use length()?

Comment: `const decimalDigits = Math.floor(Math.log10(num)) + 1;`, didn't add anything for <=0.

Comment: Why are you using a loop/counter for this. `(233826).toString().length`

Answer (score -1):

You need to check for `> 1` not `> 0` but you can also get the string length (as long as it is a positive integer)

```js
let num = 233826;
let count = 0;
document.write('hmm: ',num.toString().length,'<br>');
do {
  num = num/10;
  ++count;
} while (num > 1)
document.write("Total words are ", count);
```